# Create columns in text file

Tags: software-recommendation, text-processing

I have used a text-from-image generator to pull info from a image of a glossary that look like this:

```
word1      :meaning1
word2      :meaning2
word3      :meaning3
word4      :meaning4
```

Which resulted in a text file looking like this:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
:meaning1
:meaning2
:meaning3
:meaning4
```

I feel like this is a common occurrence when copying glossary-like texts from pdf documents as well. Is there any handy way to recreate the original text disposition? Preferably create columns where the words and meanings are linked, even better if it is without cells.

I guess I'm looking for a way to paste/attach the content of several rows to the ends of several existing rows.

The only solution I can think of is to paste everything into LibreOffice writer and choose columns, but that would only recreate the source document presentation-wise and there is no real use of that.

**The question is:**

How to change the extracted text into two columns so that it looks like it was in the picture i.e. like:

```
word1      :meaning1
word2      :meaning2
word3      :meaning3
word4      :meaning4
```

I would prefer GUI tools, but non-advanced CLI solutions are also appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an advanced text editor or IDE such as [Geany](https://www.geany.org).

E.g. with Geany you can edit text vertically maintaining `Ctrl` while selecting it with your mouse.

Once selected "vertically" just paste it at the end of your first line, then press tab as many time as you want, depending on the space you need between columns.

Answer (score 0):

Non-advanced CLI solutions with the `pr` command:

```
$ pr -T2 < file.txt
word1                               :meaning1
word2                               :meaning2
word3                               :meaning3
word4                               :meaning4
```

or with the `rs` command:

```
$ rs -t 0 2 < file.txt
word1      :meaning1
word2      :meaning2
word3      :meaning3
word4      :meaning4
```

Comment: pr command had an issue with dealing with too many lines of text, as it divided the output into separate "pages", resulting in jumbling of the text.

rs -t 0 2 < file.txt worked when adding the flag -e to read every row as an entry rather than reading whitespace separated strings as entries.
Apparantly my text mass had whitespace in it that I did not represent in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Mid-advanced CLI solution with [`awk`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/awk.1posix.html):

```
$ cat file
word1
word2
word3
word4
:meaning1
:meaning2
:meaning3
:meaning4
```

Either based on RegEx patterns i.e. leading colon `^:` or no leading colon `^[^:]` (*assuming that is consistent*) like so:

```
$ awk '/^[^:]/ {
        wrd[i++] = $0
}

/^:/ {
        def[j++] = $0
}

END {
        for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                printf "%s\t%s\n", wrd[k], def[k]
        }
}' file
word1   :meaning1
word2   :meaning2
word3   :meaning3
word4   :meaning4
```

Or based on line numbers i.e. splitting the file into first half and last half like so:

```
$ awk '{
        lines[NR] = $0
}

END {
        k = NR / 2 + 1
        for (j = 1; j <= NR / 2; j++) {
                printf "%s\t%s\n", lines[j], lines[k++]
        }
}' file
word1   :meaning1
word2   :meaning2
word3   :meaning3
word4   :meaning4
```